# Providing partial input to a bash command

Tags: bash, pipe

Say I'm running some command `foo`, which prompts the user for various things. I want to provide values for the first few prompts, but enter the rest manually (i.e. on `stdin`).

How can I do this? I've tried

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | foo
```

This accepts all the inputs, but then gets an `EOF` from the input stream. I've also tried

```
foo <(echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" & cat /dev/stdin)
```

which didn't work either.

Comment: expect search for strings in output so he would have to output his variables names to console - that said it simpler with "read"

Comment: Unless you use a tool like expect, you can either read from stdin or read from the tty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is most likely that `foo` is not designed to take a filename as an argument. (Keep in mind that `<(...)` doesn't pass `...`'s output on standard-input; rather, it gets [expanded to a special filename](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) that can be read from to obtain `...`'s output.) To fix this, you can add another `<`:

```
foo < <(echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" ; cat /dev/stdin)
```

or use a pipeline:

```
{ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" ; cat /dev/stdin ; } | foo
```

(Note that I changed the `&` to `;`, by the way. The former would work, but is a bit strange, given that you intend for `echo` to handle the first several inputs.)

Answer (score 0):

ask user for what you want and then relay that to your command

```
echo "Question 1: "; read ans1;
echo "Question 2: "; read ans2;
./foo bar bar "$ans1" baz "$ans2"
```

maybe like that? it's simple and efficient :)